# Instantly redirect to URL that has been scraped from google search results

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

Recently, I was wondering if the web scraper written in PHP could instantly redirect to the 1st url fetched on google search.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry&oq=raspberry&aqs&num=1');

$linkObjs = $html->find('div[class=jfp3ef] a');
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
        $title = trim($linkObj->plaintext);
        $link = trim($linkObj->href);

        //if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
        if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
            $link = $matches[1];
        } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
            continue;
        }

        echo $link . '</p>';
}
?>
```

The code fetches 1st top result from the google search of "raspberry" and prints the url of that site. I want it to redirect it to that url and not print it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php's built-in `header()` function. You will use it like this:

```
header("Location: $link");
```

Please note that if the link in the $link variable doesn't have a `http` or `https` prefix it may not redirect correctly so you may want to check if it exists first. If it doesn't just preprend it and do the redirect.

Also, don't use `echo` or any other statement that outputs something to the screen before calling the `header()` function because that won't work either.